# How to set a certain limit to my output?

Tags: bash, shell

Uhm to explain what I'm trying to do is basically to create a shell-script which will disect number of file sizes into certain categories, for example:

> Number of files <100B:
>   Number of files <1MB:
>    Number of files <1GB:

you get the point.
So far i've got this

```
find $PWD -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | cut -d" " -f5 | sort -n
```

basically what this does is looks for files only, writes their file size, cuts only their file size and sorts them from lowest to highest.

So for example an output (STDOUT) would look like this:

```
 3   
 2184   
 5709
 15006
```

Issue is, I'm not sure how can i get this STDOUT and somehow set basically a filesize limit (let's say in this case 100B) so basically it would in this case only print the number 3. Any idea how to this? Or maybe some completely different but more effetive method of doing this altogether?

Comment: Read in the `find` documentation in section "Finding Files" the subsection "2.4 Size", e.g. use the `-size` test

Comment: @LarsFischer yup found it, thanks for the refference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` with `-size`:

```
tmp1=$(find $PWD -size -100c | wc -l)
tmp2=$(find $PWD -size -1M | wc -l)
tmp3=$(find $PWD -size -1G | wc -l)

echo "Number of files <100B: $tmp1"
echo "Number of files <1MB: $tmp2"
echo "Number of files <1GB: $tmp3"
```